# Is it possible to add a driver to a vertex position?

Tags: transforms, drivers

I want to add a driver to a vertex' z position. Is this possible? If it is, how?

When I try to add a driver, all I get is the option to edit source and edit translation.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In edit mode, select the vertex you want to animate. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > <kbd>H</kbd> (Hook to new object). This will create an empty, whose position you can animate, and the selected vertex will follow it.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 8):

You could also add [Shape Keys](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Techs/Shape/Shape_Keys) and animate the influence, either by adding keyframes directly or by a driver.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question specifically: Yes. It is possible.

Go to **Outliner**, switch Display Mode to *Datablocks*, then you'll see a list of all datablocks for the .blend file.

Expand the list: **Blendfile Data** > **Objects** > **your_obj_name** > **Data** > **mashdata_name** > **Vertices** > **Mesh Vertex** > **Location**, then you can right click on X Y Z, and choose *Add Drivers* or *Add Single Driver* from the menu.

[image]

However, when there are too many vertices, it will be very hard to target the one you want. I would rather use hooks.