# Can't insert drive to Transform ​belong to edit mode?

Tags: transforms, drivers

I want to insert a drive into the transform of the bone's head or object's vertex, but I can't insert it. Is it impossible to insert itself?

2020-12-20 updated
I found a way to drive the object's vertex. No bones. This is the link. [Is it possible to add a driver to a vertex position?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23793/is-it-possible-to-add-a-driver-to-a-vertex-position)
[image: text]

2021-01-18
My update is too late. I thought I solved the problem, but it wasn't. I accessed the Outliner's Data API, but it was impossible to modify the value in Object Mode. [image: text] [image: text]

Comment: Possibly can with vert coordinates https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/how-to-keyframe-mesh-vertices-in-python  .. not sure it's doable (nor advisable) with edit bones.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I searched more, and when I accessed the Data API, it was possible to drive. Unfortunately, no bones. I'm looking for another way. 
This is a link to the article. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23793/is-it-possible-to-add-a-driver-to-a-vertex-position

Comment: please add a answer to your question and mark it as solved so that this will help other people who search for a similar thing